# Transfer Razor variable between two div elements

Tags: asp.net, variables, razor, view, model

I have a foreach loop inside one `<div>` element.

```
@foreach (var patient in Model.Patients)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patient.FirstName)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patient.LastName)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patient.PersonalID)</td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@patient.Id" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>  Edit</a>
                                <a onclick="showDetails()" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>  Detail</a>
                                <form asp-action="DeleteUser" asp-route-id="@patient.Id" method="post" style="display: inline;">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger">
                                        Delete
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
```

How can I save the @patient.Id element when a user clicks Details button

```
<a onclick="showDetails()" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>  Detail</a>
```

So that I can use it in the same View but in a different `<div>` element.

I have decleared another variable at the beggining of the body.

```
<body>
@{ var patientId = 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is pretty simple. pass selected button to JavaScript function and retrieve 3 child of current row that is current patient id :

```
<script>
function showDetails(elem) {
    var patientid = elem.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].innerText;
    alert("Hello\n" + patientid);
}
```

```
<table>
    @foreach (var patient in Model.Patients)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patient.FirstName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patient.LastName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patient.Id)</td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@patient.Id" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>  Edit</a>
                <a onclick="showDetails(this)" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>  Detail</a>
                <form asp-action="DeleteUser" asp-route-id="@patient.Id" method="post" style="display: inline;">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Here is output:
[image]